# How to sort bounding boxes from left to right?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection-api, tensorflow-model-garden

I am using tensorflow object detection API to detect text on images. It gives me a good result with very good accuracy. How can i sort the bounding boxes from left to right so as to make the text in a readable form.

Answer (score 0):

A simple trick would be to sort the output bounding boxes according their xmin coordinates. For the y coordinate, just take the mean of ymin and ymax and put all with the same mean plus a samll tolerace together in a list. This way, you get ordered columns and rows